# Node Upgrade with nuxt causing error Rule can only have one resource source

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, npm-install

I have a web app and I am trying to upgrade the node version to be 18.4.0. I have the following package.json. I think it is due to my web-pack version but no matter what i try i get errors.

```
{
  "name": "new-app-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "nuxt build",
    "start": "node ./pm2.js",
    "dev": "node ./pm2.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "heroku-prebuild": "bash heroku-prebuild.sh",
    "heroku-cleanup": "bash heroku-cleanup.sh",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production npm run postinstall && NODE_ENV=production npm start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "1.2.1",
    "@nuxtjs/svg-sprite": "0.5.2",
    "aos": "3.0.0-beta.6",
    "axios": "0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "1.19.0",
    "cheerio": "1.0.0-rc.3",
    "chokidar": "3.4.1",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "dat-gui": "0.5.0",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "gsap": "3.2.6",
    "lazysizes": "5.2.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.19",
    "lottie-web": "5.7.0",
    "moment": "2.25.3",
    "mongoose": "5.9.10",
    "morgan": "1.10.0",
    "nuxt": "2.15.8",
    "pm2": "4.4.0",
    "sitemap": "2.2.0",
    "svg4everybody": "2.1.9",
    "vue-client-only": "2.0.0",
    "vue-masonry": "0.10.12",
    "vue-masonry-css": "1.0.3",
    "vue-waypoint": "3.4.1",
    "vuex": "3.3.0",
    "webpack": "5.73.0",
    "webpack-glsl-loader": "1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "eslint": "8.18.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "9.1.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.6.0",
    "node-sass": "7.0.1",
    "normalize-scss": "7.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-pxtorem": "5.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1"
    },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.4.0",
    "npm": "8.13.2"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm install` I get the following error

> Nuxt Fatal Error
> │    │
> │    │   Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided
> resource and test + include + exclude) in {   │    │   "use": [
> │    │   {
> │    │   "loader":
> "C:\web\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js",            │
> │   "options": {
> │    │   "configFile": false,
> │    │   "babelrc": false,
> │    │   "cacheDirectory": false,
> │    │   "envName": "client",
> │    │   "presets": [
> │    │   [
> │    │
> "C:\web\node_modules\@nuxt\babel-preset-app\src\index.js",
> │    │   {
> │    │   "corejs": {
> │    │   "version": 2
> │    │   }
> │    │   }
> │    │   ]
> │    │   ]
> │    │   },
> │    │   "ident": "clonedRuleSet-4.use[0]"
> │    │   }
> │    │   ]
> │    │   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Resolved this by removing node-sass and by adding sass:1.54.0. I Also upgraded the sass-loader to version 10.3.1